# signature of Object.getClass() method

Tags: java, generics

The class Object contains the following method:

```
public final Class<? extends Object> getClass().
```

why the return type of this method is `Class<? extends Object>`

Comment: I've just had a look on the Jdk (1.6 update 20) implementation, and I see that the getClass() method return a Class<?>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Java lacks [self types](http://blogs.oracle.com/ahe/entry/selftypes). (If it had them, then the return type would be `Class<? extends self_type>`). So the signature merely declares `Class<?>`, the (next) best it can do, which is less than ideal - the compiler certainly knows that `getClass()` doesn't return any class, but a class that is a **subtype** of the static type of the expression on which `getClass()` is invoked.

Thus we have this singularity, where the signature of the method declares `Class<?>` because of limitations of the language, but the compiler treats the return value as `Class<? extends TheClass>` because it knows it is safe and wants to be helpful :)

PS: you saw `Class<? extends Object>` because you called `getClass()` on an expression with the static type of `Object`.

Comment: That's it. Your explanation helps to understand the javadoc of Object#getClass!

Comment: Yes, thanks Dimitris :)
I use IDEA, and when I ask to create a variable from obj.getClass(), it automatically create one of type Class<? extends Obj>.

Comment: Ah, I was just adding the PS: to make it clearer :) (btw, hello again!)

Answer (score 2):

This was actually a bug in JDK 1.5. Also see [this topic](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=496028&forumID=316) and [this bugreport](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5004321). In a nut, this signature caused that the following snippet didn't compile while it *should*:

```
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println(l1.getClass() == l2.getClass()); // Incompatible types?
```

They fixed it in 1.6 by changing the return type to [`Class<?>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) instead of [`Class<? extends Object>`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

Because, the generic construct `? extends Object` matches any Java object which extends Object. Since everything in Java inherits from Object, this matches everything loaded on the classpath. In this case, without using `Class<? extends Object>` the `Object.getClass()` method would only ever be able to return the Class of Object, and not the Class object representing the actual concrete type as most developers would expect.

Answer (score 1):

The actual signature (at least in 1.6) is

```
public final Class<?> getClass()
```

According to the javadocs :

> The actual result type is Class where |X| is the erasure
>   of the static type of the expression
>   on which getClass is called. For
>   example, no cast is required in this
>   code fragment:
>
> Number n = 0;
>   Class < ? extends Number>  c = n.getClass();

If you didn't have a parameterized return value, you'd have to cast even if you had type information available at runtime. So the above example would end up as

```
Class c = n.getClass(); //c now has no type information
```

Answer (score 0):

The getClass() method is (usually) used to check if a class is of a particular type

```
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass();

if (myClass.getClass().equals(myClass2.getClass())
{
  // do stuff
}
```

The return type is a Class object because you can compare it to other Class object. It extends Object because everything extends object in Java.

Another use of getClass() is to use getName() so that

```
myClass1.getClass().getName()
```

returns `MyClass`

It can help you instanciate classes by string name via reflection

```
string className = myClass1.getClass().getName();
MyClass newInstance = (MyClass) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

Comment: It suffices to use `myclass instanceof MyClass`.